# Mount Azure Web App Files' folder into VM?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

how do I mount an azure webb app folder on VM, I've a webb App and a Virtual Machine and I need to mount the web app files and folders to my VM.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s a local VM, you cannot mount the drive. However, you have ways to copy files/folders to and from Azure App Service. 
You could use an FTP app or Kudu service. 
Based on the WebApp App Service Plan the volume of the storage varies. You could use Kudu console (https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net) to manage the files- it gives you both command line and file browser access to your sites, all from the comfort of a web browser.

Every Azure WebApp has a home directory stored/backed by Azure Storage. It is owned by Azure WebApp Service and cannot be chosen currently; however, you could select storage account for Azure WebApp Diagnostic logs.

Additionally, one of the unique aspects of App Service that makes app deployment and maintenance straightforward is that all user content is stored on a set of UNC shares. This model maps well to the common pattern of content storage used by on-premises web hosting environments that have multiple load-balanced servers.
Within App Service, there is a number of UNC shares created in each datacenter. A percentage of the user content for all customers in each data center is allocated to each UNC share. Furthermore, all of the file content for a single customer's subscription is always placed on the same UNC share.

Also, mapping Azure File Share isn't supported on Azure App Service:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6084609-allow-map-azure-file-share-microsoft-azure-file-s

Answer (score 1):

it's impossibe,

you must use one of the five Azure auto deploy option, (Github, Bitbuket etc ..)